# Sublime text. Keep find in files panel open after running search and/or replace operation

Tags: find-and-replace, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, find-in-files

I am using `Find in files` functionality of sublime text regularly (default key binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)

Pannel can be hidden by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Whenever I hit `Find` the pannel itself disappears after operation is performed. It can be called again by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

I wonder if this behavior can be changed so that panel is permanently visible and does not disappear during search operation unless explicitely closed by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Windows 10 enterprise

Comment: See if the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404032/find-replace-panel-in-sublime-text-disappears-after-replace-all) also solve the problem, especially the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, I read this post while doing my initial research. This does not answer my question. I also attempted to adapt solution to my case but it does not seem to work. The difference is that post you linked is related to an action triggered by shortcut. For action that I am looking at there appears to be no shortcut. It is a button on the panel... Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right. I see that there exist many posts for the same problem, but with no solution. Perhaps someone else knows a solution that isn't a kludge (like automatic Ctrl+Shift+F).